# Copy vector to struct

Tags: vector, struct, memcpy, c++98

I have a structure

```
struct 
{
  unsigned char data[6];    // switches
  unsigned char name[12];   // entry name
  unsigned char desc[16];   // entry description
} TOC; // table of contents
```

and a `vector <unsigned char> midiData` of 41 bytes, 34 of which represent the values that should fill the above struct TOC, starting from byte n. 6 (0-index).

So I do:

```
memcpy(&TOC, &midiData[6], 34);
```

This compiles, but what I get is the expected characters plus unwanted ones. Where's the problem?

**EDIT:**

vector midiData contains:

240 117 38 9 85 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 84 101 115 116 32 78 97 109 101 32 49 32 84 101 115 116 32 68 101 115 99 114 105 112 116 105 111 110 247

TOC.name contains: Test Name 1

TOC.desc contains: Test Description5èBVÄÿ5¤¦l

Comment: In given example, if it is exactly as written, should be no padding. You need to show actual data of vector and what results you're getting.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm on VS2013, compiler supports C++11 but I want it to be compatible with C++98 because I'll have to compile the same code on GCC 4.2.

Comment: `midiData` is missing `\0` bytes at the end if each "sub-string", except first one (corresponding to `data` field), therefore you have to add one manually to indicate end of string.